# Javascript simular keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ola, tenho o seguinte caso, uma página externa é aberta dentro do meu iframe, preciso que o javascript simule a tecla "TAB" até chegar no campo de login. ate ai tanto faz por que meu problema esta em achar uma maneira de faze-lo simular esse "TAB" sem que nenhum outro evento tenha sido dispardo, apenas o carregamento da página.

segue exemplo, mas nao

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"> </script>';

?>

<html>


<iframe src="http://alelo.com.br/consulta-saldo-extrato-alelo.html" style="width:100%; height:100%">

<script>

alert('.-.');

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Explique mais o que você deseja, a pergunta não está clara.

Comment: sumular uma tecla, quando a pag carregar quero q seja simulado "tab" ate chegar no campo do numer do cartão.

Comment: Marquei como duplicada da tua outra pergunta. Como eu tinha respondido lá esse dominio não permite CORS, e não vai ser possivel aceder ao `document` dessa página.

Comment: event d keyboard nao tem nada a ver com o cors mas marque como quiser, se não sabe como so deixa ai ate alguem que saiba responder vlw!

Comment: So simular um tab... isso nao pode ser tao dificil

Comment: @RaphaelAraujo para manipulares um _tab_ tens de mexer nos eventos da iframe para disparar `keypress`, então tens de ter acesso ao `document` e o CORS não está ligado nesse site. Não é má vontade, alguns sites desligam o CORS para prevenir que um programa tente por exemplo fazer login e testar senhas até acertar.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja isso que você quer, somente a utilização do atributo "autofocus" no "input".

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>focus demo</title>
<style>
    span {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><input autofocus type="text"> <span>Login</span></p>
<p><input type="password"> <span>Senha</span></p>

<script>
    $( "input" ).focus(function() {
        $( this ).next( "span" ).css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( 1000 );
    });
</script>
```

Automaticamente ao carregar a página o foco é dado ao primeiro input que da página.

Comment: Obrigado pela respota, mas no meu caso os inputs que eu quero nao são da minha pagina, são de outra pag que esta na web, sendo assim nao posso colocar o atributo autofocus pois o input nao é meu.